# Range.Autofill method gives error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple code and it does not work. Please give me a hint what is wrong. As I have no idea... :(
The error that appears is:

Run-time error '1004'
AutoFill method of Range class failed

debugger highlights the last line of the code.
please see the code below:
`Sub why_u_no_work()`
`Dim b As Integer`
`Dim lastrowincurrfund As Integer`
`Dim fundslistsym(0 To 0) As String`
`Dim SourceRange As Range`
`Dim fillRange As Range`

`lastrowincurrfund = 142`
`b = 0`
`fundslistsym(b) = "DU"`
`Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fundslistsym(b)).Range("P1:AC1")`
`Set fillRange = Range("P1:AC" & lastrowincurrfund)`
`SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange, Type:=xlFillDefault`
`End Sub`

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The code is working perfectly in my machine. Make sure the worksheet name is "DU"

Comment: The worksheets name is "DU". Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in assinging fillRange variable:
I have updated it, check and let me know:

```
Sub why_u_no_work()

    Dim b As Integer
    Dim lastrowincurrfund As Integer
    Dim fundslistsym(0 To 0) As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim fillRange As Range

    lastrowincurrfund = 142
    b = 0
    fundslistsym(b) = "DU"
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fundslistsym(b)).Range("P1:AC1")
    Set fillRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fundslistsym(b)).Range("P1:AC" & lastrowincurrfund)
    SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub why_u_no_work()

    Dim b As Integer
    Dim lastrowincurrfund As Integer
    Dim fundslistsym(0 To 0) As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim fillRange As Range

    lastrowincurrfund = 142
    b = 0
    fundslistsym(b) = "DU"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fundslistsym(b))
        Set SourceRange = .Range("P1:AC1")
        Set fillRange = .Range("P1:AC" & lastrowincurrfund)
        SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange, Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution.
The Range.Autofill method does not work if the sheet in which the method is going to be used is not active. So to overcome the probelm one has to just add:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fundslistsym(b)).Activete

and that is all...
I manged to make the code run, yet I do not understand why activating the sheet is required. If anyone can help with tht please tell me. I am so eager to know why it is like that.
Many thanks
Artur